# pandas concat successful but error message following stops loop

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm getting the error message

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

When using pd.concat, but the concat appears to be successful as when I try and print the resulting dataframe it does so successfully but the error message terminates the loop.

```
state_list = ['Colorado', 'Ilinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri', 'Nebraska',\
             'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Pennsylvania', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Wisconsin']


    for state_name in state_list:
        ### DF1 is a dataframe unique to each state###
        condition_categories = (df1['description'].unique())
        cats = []
        for cat in condition_categories:
            category_df = df1[['week', 'value']].where(df1['description'] == cat).dropna()
            category_df = category_df.set_index('week')
            category_df = category_df.rename(columns={'value': str(cat)})
            category_df.week = dtype=np.int
            cats.append(category_df)
            #print(category_df)

        df = pd.concat(cats, axis =1) 
        print(df)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have an empty data frame when you are doing the selection?  Try printing the head of the return value of the first selection.

Comment: have just printed the head of df1 and can confirm that it's not an empty DF.

Comment: What about head of the category_df?

Comment: Have done this also and prints each series correctly. Oddly enough it seemed to work when I ran the code inputting one state manually but the error occurs when using a for loop

Comment: Other than the outside for loop has no bearing on the inside for loop, I would look into the list before concatenation and see if you find an error there.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response. Looks like there is some issue with "cats" list. It is empty in one of the iterations of outer for loop.
You can add a condition just above concatination line. Like below, it may work.

```
if len(cats) > 0:
    df = pd.concat(cats, axis =1)
else:
    print("No records to concatinate")
```